# Estrutura de pastas MVC PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Estou criando um projeto MVC em PHP e me surgiu a dúvida de como devo criar a estrutura das pastas corretamente. Fiz um modelo de pastas baseado nos projetos que  encontrei no GitHub porém não sei se é a melhor forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só nessa imagem já falta padrão na minha visão, os nomes de pasta uns tão maiúsculos outra minúsculos, pasta imagem fora do conjunto css, js bom realmente a organização de pastas é importante mas, também a nomenclatura.

Comment: certo vou me atentar a isso, mas quanto a estrutura de pastas pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Acho que poderia ser `App -> Controller` e `App -> Model` e `App -> View` e `App -> Public ` e `App -> Vendor` para iniciar.

Comment: Se não me engano, a pasta `vendor`, criada pelo composer, é estritamente em minúsculo o nome.

Comment: Atente-se a utilizar as nomenclaturas corretamente. Independente do nome que vc colocar, deve-se seguir maiúsculo e minúsculo na hora de incluir os arquivos destas pastas. A `vendor` deve ser minúscula, conforme o próprio Composer já cria. Lembre-se: o sistema de arquivos do Windows é case-insensitive. Já o Linux não!

Comment: Alguém poderia me passar um link de projeto com uma estrutura semelhante que esteja correta ?

Comment: Não existe uma estrutura correta. Você estrutura da forma que atender às suas necessidades, não às dos outros. Ficar comparando com projetos avulsos não te trará nenhum benefício.

Answer (score 6):

Mano basicamente, para um estrutura de projetos que segue o Padrão MVC, você poderia ter basicamente 3 diretórios: `Model`, `View` e `Controller`. Cada pasta deve conter os arquivos de responsabilidade ao qual se refere... É bem comun estes 3 diretórios estarem dentro de um diretório pai chamado `src(source)` que fica na raíz do projeto. Na raíz podem existir outros diretórios como o `Public`, que irá conter os arquivos que ficarão expostos para a Web, também podem existir alguns arquivos de configuração como `bootstrap.php` ou `composer.json` (caso use e recomendo que use).

Basicamente poderia ficar assim:

```
projeto-php
├── bootstrap.php
├── composer.json
├── config
├── public
│   └── index.php
├── src
│   ├── Controller
│   ├── Model
│   ├── Services
│   └── View
└── vendor
```